# Failure to match article and word

Tags: regex

I want to match an indefinite article and the word it accompanies:

For instance, I would like to match from the following sentences.

```
An animal is coming.
```

-> `An animal`

```
I saw a dog.
```

-> `a dog`

I am using the following regex, which to me seems good:

```
(\b)*[Aa]\b[a-z]*(\b)*
```

However, it doesn't work in my code.

I have also tested it here http://regexr.com/ but there seems to be no match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `\b([Aa]n? [a-z]+)\b`?

https://regex101.com/r/tI3dZ5/1

Answer (score 1):

([Aa]n?\s+\w+) which translates to:
either A or a , followed by an optional 'n', then 1 whitespace or more and then a string of alphanumeric characters